# From an array of objects, print a list of only one object property (Python)

Tags: python, json, api

This is my first time using Python and I'm tasked with the following: print a list of cities from this JSON: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I'm trying to print out a list that should read:
Gwenborough
Wisokyburgh
McKenziehaven
South Elvis
etc.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import json
import requests
response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
users = json.loads(response.text)
print(users)
```

When I run `$python3 -i api.py` (file is named api.py) I'm able to print the list from the JSON file in my terminal. However I have been stuck trying to figure out how to print the cities only. I'm assuming it would look something like `users.address.city` but any attempt at figuring out the code has resulted in the following error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'address'`.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `users` is a list -- you want to access an attribute of one element, e.g. `users[0].get('<attribute_name>')`

Answer (score 1):

As `users` is a list, it should be:

```
print(users[0]['address']['city'])
```

This is how you can access nested properties in JSON response.

You can also loop over the users and print their city in the same format.

```
for user in users:
    print(user['address']['city'])
```

Comment: I knew I had to use a for loop, but couldn't quite figure out the syntax for extracting the city property. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get city name with user['address']['city']
and use loop to get all city names
like this

```
for user in users:
    print(user['address']['city'])
```

output :

```
Gwenborough
Wisokyburgh
McKenziehaven
South Elvis
Roscoeview
South Christy
Howemouth
Aliyaview
Bartholomebury
Lebsackbury

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        first of all i get this, why your loading(response.text) , instead requests package has a built in .json() method which is what you want to access nested data . so you could do something like this 
        
        response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        data = response.json()
        
        # optional
        print(data)
        
        * loop through the addresses to get all the cities 
   for dt in data['address']:
    # do what you want with the data returned
```